# Is it possible to convert one unity theme into a cinnamon theme?

Tags: unity, themes, cinnamon

I found a very nice theme but it seems for other DE, not for cinnamon.
I'd like to know if and how I can have the same result on cinnamon.

Thank you.

[link to the theme](https://github.com/anmoljagetia/Flatabulous)

Comment: **To close voters:** This question applies to the Cinnamon Desktop in Ubuntu just as much to Linux Mint. Therefore, it is *on topic* on AU.

Answer (score 1):

No. At least not without manually creating a Cinnamon theme that looks like the Unity theme.

Cinnamon is a fork of Gnome Shell while Unity is a desktop shell that Canonical built on top of Metacity or compatible window managers (e. g. Compiz). The two are not compatible in any way.

I'm not aware of any automated conversion method.